# Calculating the number of variables and constants in a term

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm reading Kees Doets's *Basic Model Theory* and couldn't get around the first exercise, which is rather simple (no doubt my lack of arithmetical skills played a part). Let $t$ be a term and let $n_i$ ($i = 1, 2, 3, \dots$) be the number of $i$-ary function symbols that occur in $t$. The exercise is to provem by term induction, that the number of variables and constants in $t$ is $1+\sum_i(i-1) n_i$, that is, $1 + n_2 + 2n_3 + \dots$.

The base case is obvious. As for the induction step, suppose $t$ is $f(t_1, \dots, t_k)$. The induction hypothesis hold for each $t_l (1 \leq l \leq k)$, so we know that, for each such $t_l$, the above formula holds. Further, we know that the number of variables and constants in $t$ is the sum of the number of constants and variables in each $t_l$ (right?). Here comes my problem: doesn't that result in the number $k + \sum_i(i-1)n_i$? Where did I go wrong? It's probably something very simple, but I couldn't figure out what, exactly, is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ihe number of occurrences of $k$-ary function symbols in $f(t_1,\dots,t_k)$ is $1$ more than the sum of the numbers of occurrences of $k$-ary function symbols in the $t_i$.

More formally, if $n_k$ is the combined number of occurrences of $k$-ary function symbols in the $t_i$, then the number $n'_k$ of occurrences of $k$-ary function symbols in $f(t_1,\dots,t_k)$ is given by $n'_k=1+n_k$.

In the formula, the summand $(k-1)n_k$ becomes $(k-1)n'_k$, that is, $(k-1)+(k-1)n_k$.

That yields an additional $k-1$ in the sum, and your $k$ in front is $1+(k-1)$.

Comment: So I wasn't totally wrong. Just to see if I got it: the idea is that $k + \sum_i (i-1)n_i = 1 + (k-1) + \sum_i(i-1)n_i = 1 + (k-1) + n_2 + \dots + (k-1)n_k + \dots = 1 +n_2 + \dots + (k-1)n_k + (k-1) + \dots = 1 + n_2 + \dots +(k-1)n_k' + \dots$, right? (Sorry for the long string)

Comment: Yes, that's it. The $f$ in front changes the old sum $n_k$ to $n_k'=n_k+1$. You were essentially finished in what you wrote out in the OP, apart from noting that $k-1$ of your $k$ in front is accounted for in the sum by the occurrence of $f$.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot, that was very helpful.

Comment: You are welcome. One annoying thing about these arguments about syntax is that they are notationally dense, even when a simple idea is involved.